# Unable to delete item via List service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I have a console job that does some comparison on documents in a SharePoint library, and then deletes some of the documents.

However, the deletion fails for some documents, with the below error:

```
<ErrorCode>0x80070005</ErrorCode>
<ErrorText>Access denied.

You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</ErrorText>
```

What could be the issue?

I have checked the document library, and the individual documents, and verified that the concerned account has delete permissions. In fact, many other documents are getting deleted from the same library.

It cannot be that somebody else has the document open somewhere; I have not been able to delete some documents for over an year.

p.s. the delete method is called via `listService.UpdateListItems(libraryname, XML)`

Comment: are you able to manually delete those documents? try turning off versioning then try deleting.

Comment: I am able to delete manually, and versioning is also off.

Comment: what are the exact permissions for the user being used for deletion. try giving full control over site, or add in site coll admins so it gains more privileges

Comment: The account has Full Control permissions